# how to write code to find gmail, hotmail, skype friends

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gmail, skype

Sometimes on sites there is a functionality that You enter Your email and site suggests You which people You can invite to visit the site by displaying users contacts in Box.

How is it achieved ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: By using their respective APIs ([Google's one](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/) )

Comment: you can try with hotmail with this link http://www.top4download.com/free-hotmail-contacts-asp-net/